# Having tabs and none tabs regions in the same container

Tags: prism, wpf-4.0, prism-4

I have the two classics areas toolbar and content.
My problem is that I want to have different forms / areas that have tabs in the same region.

One of the areas / form have a document search form and when you click on a row in the search result a document is displayed in a new tab. The user will see a tab for the search form and a tab for each document.

when I click on the menu to show another form e.g. Administration I want to show the administration form in the same content area and when I i click on the search document menu I want to go back to my previous search result.

Do I create a form without content with only and area for the search form? or can areas coexist?
I am using the prism navigation framework.

Right now I have created a search form with only a tabregion and nothing else. The problem is that prism can't navigate to the searchform region before the form is loaded. Thats not a big problem, I can use the regionmanger to load the form if it's not loaded. I just wonder if prism somehow can handle this without custom code.

[image: Searchform][image: Administration]

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would have a particular **Region** on which you want to show an **Administration** View or a **Search** View. Moreover, you would have multiples tabs when showing the **Search** View. If this is the case, you could accomplish it by haveing a **MenuRegion** where **Administration** and **Search** Views are registered, and  defining only a **SearchTabRegion** in the **SearchView** where you would add each **TabView**. If I described a different scenario, it would be helpful if you could explain further the App flow. Regards.

Comment: Thanks that is more or less what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above on the question, the scenario you described would be a particular **Region** on which you want to show an ***Administration*** or a ***Search View***, and multiple tabs aside when showing the **Search View**.

You could accomplish this scenario by having a **MenuRegion** where ***Administration and Search Views*** are registered, and defining then a ***`SearchTabRegion`*** on a `TabsControl` in the ***`SearchContentView`*** where you would add each ***TabView***.

You may find more related information on the ***UI Composition* Prism Guide** chapter:

- [7: Composing the User Interface Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Regards.